# parseInt returning wrong values for values lower than 10^-7

Tags: javascript, parseint

`parseInt(0.000001)` returns 0

But

`parseInt(0.0000001)` returns 1

---

Does anyone happen to know the reason for this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If the number is greater than 1e+21 (including) or less than 1e-7 (including), it will return 1. (when using radix/base 10).**

e.g.

```js
console.log(parseInt(0.0000001));
console.log(parseInt(0.000000123));
console.log(parseInt(1e-7));
console.log(parseInt(1e+21));
```

checkout mdn documantation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#examples